# Помогите настроить asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, asyncio

День добрый.
У меня есть код, который по очереди вызывает модули.
Первый и последний модули должны удалить файлы, оставшиеся после предыдущего запуска.

Со второго по пятый - по очереди: загружают выбранные файлы с ресурса, распаковывают архивы и извлекают указанные файлы, перереформатируют и перекрашивают и, наконец публикуют.

В синхронном режиме все работает, но долго. Есть у меня идея прикрутить туда asyncio, чтоб после загрузки первого из файлов его сразу же подхватывал следующий модуль, но что-то не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Код:

```
import sys
import glob, os
import datetime
import time
import subprocess
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ALL_COMPLETED

start_time = time.time()

startDate = sys.argv[1]
finishDate = sys.argv[2]


os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/delete_all.py')

async def step3():
    await step2()
    await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/sentinel_gpgeo/public/walk.py ')

async def step2():
    await step1()
    await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/walk.py ')
        
async def step1():
    await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/download_all.py '+startDate+' '+finishDate)




async def step4():
await step3()
await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/sentinel_gpgeo/public/public.py ')
    
 
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ioloop.run_until_complete(step3())
ioloop.close()



os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/delete_all.py ')

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: `os.system` полностью блокирует поток выполнения, поэтому никакой асинхронности здесь нет

Comment: @andreymal подскажите, пожалуйста, как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: использовать asyncio.create_subprocess_exec. А вообще [вот](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#running-subprocesses)

Comment: @vitidev поправил. Теперь вообще не работает то, что должно быть в асинхроне

Comment: asyncio.create_subprocess_хх у вас оторван от реальности. Вы нигде не делаете ему await. Также почему asyncio.ensure_future, а не просто await step2() - был бы смысл если бы вам нужно было ждать несколько тасков, но вы ждете одну. Но я не имел дела с питоном ниже 3.7, так что тонкостей не знаю.

Comment: @vitidev так он вроде эвейтится из функции, или я совсем ничего не понимаю. Просто я еще слабо в питоне разбираюсь

Comment: вы просто вызываете asyncio.create_subprocess_shell, он стартует и идет выполнение остального кода метода и так на выход. Никто не ждет (await) его окончания. И даже в step1 нужно писать await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell. У вас вообще должно быть await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell и await stepX везде и тогда они будут выполняться последовательно (если конечно вам не нужна параллельность)

Comment: @vitidev благодарю. Дело сдвинулось с мертвой точки. Добавил await-ы, код заработал, но выполняется все равно последовательно. Или то, что я хочу сделать вообще невозможно? Если удаляю await stepX, то тогда программа просто ничего не делает

Comment: А никто не знает что вы хотите сделать. Откуда нам знать что должно быть последовательно, а что параллельно. А потому вам указали на явные ошибки "вроде бы asyncio, а await не видно". await это "асинхронно подождать в этом месте". И если нужно не ждать, а параллельность, то вот тут и нужно asyncio.ensure_future, который сделает вам таску, которую вы где то потом сделаете await где нужно ждать.

Answer (score 1):

Огромное спасибо тем, кто комментировал и подсказывал новичку.

В благодаря помощи сообщества, а так же методом проб и ошибок было выяснено, что для решения данной задачи asyncio с subprocess не подходит. Выполнение кода на средних объемах загружаемых данных замедляется более чем в два раза, а именно с приблизительно 2400 секунд(зависит от скорости скачивания запрашиваемых файлов) до.... Терпения не хватило, когда время выполнения перевалило за два часа - я убил процесс.[image: mith busted]